# Pass form data to modal component React/Boostrap

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-4, react-hooks

I have a modal component and form component. I am trying to pass the data using React hooks from the form back to the modal. I am having trouble doing this. Here is what I have so far -

Modal(Parent)

```
interface ISystem {
  systemName: string;
  allowNumber: number;
  statusCode: string;
  createdBy?: string;
  createdDate?: string;
}

const ModalForm = (props) => {

  const { buttonLabel, className } = props;

  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setModal(!modal);

  const addButtonHandler = () => {
    toggle();
   console.log(FORM DATA SHOULD BE HERE)
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button color="primary" onClick={toggle}>
        {buttonLabel}
      </Button>
      <Modal
        isOpen={modal}
        toggle={toggle}
        className={className}
        centered
        size="lg"
      >
        <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>{buttonLabel}</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          <AddSystem></AddSystem>
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button color="primary" onClick={addButtonHandler}>
            Add
          </Button>{" "}
          <Button color="secondary" onClick={toggle}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ModalForm;
```

This is my Form component

```
const AddSystem = (props) => {
  const [systemId, setSystemId] = useState("");
  const [systemName, setSystemName] = useState("");
  const [allowNumber, setAllowNumber] = useState("");
  const [statusCode, setStatusCode] = useState("");
  const [lastModifiedBy, setLastModifiedBy] = useState("");

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler} className="mx-auto">
        <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="systemId">
          <Form.Label column sm="2">
            {" "}
            ID{" "}
          </Form.Label>
          <Col sm="10">
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              name="systemId"
              placeholder="Leave blank for new system"
              value={systemId}
              disabled
              onChange={(event) => setSystemId(event.target.value)}
            />
          </Col>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="systemName">
          <Form.Label column sm="2">
            {" "}
            Systen Name{" "}
          </Form.Label>
          <Col sm="10">
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              name="systemName"
              placeholder=""
              value={systemName}
              onChange={(event) => setSystemName(event.target.value)}
            />
          </Col>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="allowNumber">
          <Form.Label column sm="2">
            {" "}
            Allow Number{" "}
          </Form.Label>
          <Col sm="10">
            <Form.Control
              as="select"
              name="allowNumber"
              value={allowNumber}
              onSelect={(event) => setAllowNumber(event.target.value)}
            >
              <option>Choose...</option>
              {["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"].map((opt) => (
                <option>{opt}</option>
              ))}
            </Form.Control>
          </Col>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="statusCode">
          <Form.Label column sm="2">
            {" "}
            Status Code{" "}
          </Form.Label>
          <Col sm="10">
            <Form.Control
              as="select"
              name="statusCode"
              value={statusCode}
              onSelect={(event) => setStatusCode(event.target.value)}
            >
              <option>Choose...</option>
              {["Active", "Draft"].map((opt) => (
                <option>{opt}</option>
              ))}
            </Form.Control>
          </Col>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="lastModifiedBy">
          <Form.Label column sm="2">
            {" "}
            Last Modified By{" "}
          </Form.Label>
          <Col sm="10">
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              name="lastModifiedBy"
              placeholder=""
              value={lastModifiedBy}
              disabled
              onChange={(event) => setLastModifiedBy(event.target.value)}
            />
          </Col>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default AddSystem;
```

I don't want to have the button inside the form. The button needs to stay in the modal footer but somehow receive information from the form...This is so that the modal can become re-usable and have any type of form passed into it perhaps

Comment: Try passing callback to `AddSystem` from your parent Modal component, which when called from Form component, will give you all required data in Modal.